# Достать из Tuple данные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю по snmp запрос на принтер и получаю tuple такого вида

```
(None, 0, 0, [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity
(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.2.1')), OctetString(hexValue='0a'))])
```

не могу понять, что это означает `hexValue='0a'` - методом проб , понял что это он пишет при открытой крышке принтера.

когда у принтера все хорошо он пишет `hexValue='00'`. Так вот хочу получать эти данные. Именно вот это `'00'`. Как мне их достать из tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете PySNMP ?

Насколько я понял из их доков вам нужно что-то вроде:

```
value = tpl[3][0][1].prettyPrint()
```

Где tpl - тот tuple, который вы получили.

Попробуйте, у меня сейчас не установлен PySNMP, сам проверить не могу.

Comment: да все верно! спасибо огромное. все работает

Comment: @shatoidil, пожалуйста, рад был помочь. Возможно, вам будет полезно почитать документацию по этому модулю. Свой ответ я писал, опираясь конкретно на эту страницу: http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html   - там в самом низу есть кусок кода, в котором в цикле выводятся на print все данные из tuple, а я просто глядя на этот цикл подобрал индексы именно под ваш вопрос.